# combine two lists into one using one by one element

Tags: python

How to combine two lists into one using one by one element as follows:

```
list1 = ['a','c','e']

list2 = ['apple','carrot','elephant']

result = ['a', 'apple', 'c', 'carrot', 'e', 'elephant']
```

Trial

```
result = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
print result
```

But they are in tuples, any easier soultion is expected...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a double-for-loop list comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = ['a','c','e']
>>> list2 = ['apple','carrot','elephant']
>>> [x for z in zip(list1, list2) for x in z]
['a', 'apple', 'c', 'carrot', 'e', 'elephant']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [4]: list1 = ['a','c','e']

In [5]: list2 = ['apple','carrot','elephant']

In [6]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))
Out[6]: ['a', 'apple', 'c', 'carrot', 'e', 'elephant']
```